# Error in reading data in python after update version 3.5 to 3.6 in ubunto 16.04

Tags: python

After updating to `Ubuntu 16.04` , I have updated `python3` version from `3.57` to `3.6` but now i can't read the data using `pandas`.

Here are the errors issued:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please copy content of your error into the post instead of posting the image (try not to post those unless absolutely necessary). For reasoning check [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: It is almost Impossible that this issue occurred because of python update

Comment: It is very unlikely that you will find a path starting with `C:/` on Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 0):

`FileNotFoundError` is the error when the file is absent from the path.

It's not a problem with Ubuntu version, you don't have `train_data.csv` you are trying to load (or the path to it is incorrect).